# How to post string to server using BasicNameValuePair

Tags: android, httpwebrequest, http-post

I'm trying to post combination of string to my backend server. How can I achieve that using `BasicNameValuePair`. Here are some code which I was trying:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("API HERE");

List<NameValuePair> postData = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "the_username"));
postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "the_password"));
```

I want to send username and password like:

`username=USER&password=PWD`

How to achieve the successful post to the server.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is what I use for all of my `POST` variables:

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

HttpPost httpPost;
httpPost = new HttpPost(Net_URL + Net_Get);

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(/*Name Value Pairs*/));

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

As a side suggestion, I would first do an some sort of encryption of a users password before sending it over the network, I have seen many who do not do this ^.^

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion. But I want to know how can send string seperated by & between username and password. Do you have any code for that. That will help me a lot. :)

Comment: As you posted `username=USER&password=PWD`, that represents a method of `GET` instead of `POST`. `POST` is sent in the header of the URL request, while `GET` is data that is appended to the end of the URL. I do not quite understand what you need, are you saying that you are looking for `GET` instead of `POST`? `GET` example: `http://www.example.com/?username=USER&password=PWD`

Comment: I have to send the username and password in the body with header as `Content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `Charset = UTF-8`.